# Not sure why I keep getting a NULL value in my array

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Novice here. I'm having major headaches with trying to get my head around sqlite3.

Every time I try to run **this method**

```
-(void)openDB
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Database failed to open");
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"database opened");
    }

}
```

So that I can pull data from my database and into a table.

I get this error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '*** -  [NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
```

Any tips?

Comment: Probably `filePath` is misbehaving. What does that look like?

Comment: Most likely `filePath` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `filePath`. Also, for converting NSStrings to file system compatible C strings, you should use the method `fileSystemRepresentation`, not `UTF8String`.